# How do I enable email verification for new user in CVAT server?

Tags: django, docker, email-verification, cvat

I am trying to enable email verification for new users that'll be registering on the server. I followed the documentation and added the following options in the "base.py" file. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
# https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM = '<email>'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<email>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password>'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# set UI url to redirect after a successful e-mail confirmation
#changed from '/auth/login' to '/auth/email-confirmation' for email confirmation message
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '/auth/email-confirmation'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SENT_REDIRECT_URL = '/auth/email-verification-sent'
INCORRECT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_URL = '/auth/incorrect-email-confirmation'

OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
```

Code - https://toscode.gitee.com/wangdong_cn_admin/cvat/blob/master/cvat/settings/base.py

Documentation - https://toscode.gitee.com/wangdong_cn_admin/cvat/blob/master/cvat/apps/documentation/installation.md#email-verification